# Create a java program to solve quadratic eqations

Tags: java, math, coding-style, computer-science

Solving a quadratic equation

The program must have two methods `quadraticEquationRoot1()` which takes as input 3 `double`s, representing `a`, `b`, `c` and returns the larger of the two roots and `quadraticEquationRoot2()` which takes as input 3 `double`s, representing `a`, `b`, and `c` (in that order) and returns the smaller of the two roots.

We assume that the numbers `a`, `b`, `c` are chosen so that the square root is never the square root of a negative number

I have the following written down so far. I am not sure on how to introduce the second method

```
public class MathUtilities
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //Note that the inputs are now declared as doubles.
        public static double quadraticEquationRoot1(double a, double b, double c)(){  
            double root1, root2; //This is now a double, too.
            root1 = (-b + Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b, 2) - 4*a*c)) / (2*a);
            root2 = (-b - Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b, 2) - 4*a*c)) / (2*a);
            return Math.max(root1, root2);  
        }

        public static double quadraticEquationRoot2(double a, double b, double c)(){
            double root1, root2; //This is now a double, too.
            root1 = (-b + Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b, 2) - 4*a*c)) / (2*a);
            root2 = (-b - Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b, 2) - 4*a*c)) / (2*a);
            return Math.min(root1, root2);  
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are aware of the `Math.min(..)` method?

Comment: I am not allowed to use Scanner or print statements either

Comment: If you may use `Math.max` I think there is a good chance you may use `Math.min`too.

Comment: Just a general comment. As you learn more about programming you'll realise that repeated code is usually harder to maintain. Have look at your code and see if you can remove the same code from happening more than once.

Comment: If i don't use Math.max or Math.min. Is there another way to solve it? A hint would help

Comment: @Khanak You can create your own min and max like this: `if(root1 > root2) { return root1; } else { return root2; }` Replace `>` with `<` for min

Comment: In my edit section I am posting a sample of my solution. However it is not compiling? I am not sure where I have gone wrong @Runemoro

Comment: @Khanak You have two parenthesis at the methods, they should be: `public static double quadraticEquationRoot2(double a, double b, double c) {`

Comment: Another mistake: Methods can't be defined inside another methods(The main method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is pretty straight forward:

```
public static double quadraticEquationRoot1(int a, int b, int c){
    double root1 = (-b + Math.pow( b*b - 2*a*c, .5 ))/(2*a);
    double root2 = (-b - Math.pow( b*b - 2*a*c, .5 ))/(2*a);
    //we have options here, use min/max, or use if statements, for example. With ifs:
    if ( root1 > root2 ){
        return root1;
    }
    return root2;
    //otherwise: return max( root1, root2 );
}
```

The method method is almost the exact same thing:

```
public static double quadraticEquationRoot2(int a, int b, int c){
    double root1 = (-b + Math.pow( b*b - 2*a*c , .5))/(2*a);
    double root2 = (-b - Math.pow( b*b - 2*a*c , .5))/(2*a);
    //we have options here, use min/max, or use if statements, for example. With ifs:
    if ( root1 < root2 ){
        return root1;
    }
    return root2;
    //otherwise: return min( root1, root2 );
}
```

Notice that the case where there's only one root is covered, by either method

Comment: Since when are java comments `#`s

Comment: Thank you @mjCSguy. I had edited it something similar as well. However, when i try to compile my method line shows an error saying "illegal start of expression"

Comment: This is naive code.  It doesn't handle special cases (e.g. a = 0); it's susceptible to overflow.  I'd keep thinking about making this better if I were you.

Comment: It certainly is. But a = 0 doesn't actually describe a quadratic equation, it describes a linear one. As this seems like a question focused on working with coding fundamentals, I would suspect that potential overflow issues aren't really a big concern. If you'd like, Khanak, I can give you a solution that isn't so susceptible.

Comment: Your illegal start exception is because of a different problem - you shouldn't be declaring methods inside of your main method. The main method is the method that gets executed when you run that file. Don't nest methods inside of it. Declare your first method, close it. Declare your second method, close it. THEN declare your main method, close it. Close the class. Done!

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to have two methods, the second one would return `Math.min(root1, root)`, with everything else being the same.

Personally, I'd rather have one method that returns a double array ( `double[]` ) or a class containing both roots.  Seems silly to go through all the work before the return statement twice without good cause.